# Git: How can I get the second latest version in date ? (when declined suffixed tags are made)

Tags: git

## description

I am using `git describe --tags` to get the latest version of my project.

I want to get the version before that one.

We run a script on each tag that will create many release followed with a `-suffix`. `git  describe --tags` work because we cut that suffix.

How can I get the version released before ?

## example

List of released version (ascending released by date):

- `v1.0.0`
- `v1.0.0-cli`
- `v1.0.7`
- `v1.0.7-cli`
- `v1.0.8`
- `v1.0.8-cli`
- `v1.1.0`
- `v1.1.0-cli`

`v1.1.0-cli` is the latest tag, so we get the latest `v1.1.0` that way, now the version before this one (in date) is `v1.0.8`, how do we get it?

Comment: Is your working copy at `v1.1.0-cli` or `v1.1.0`?

Comment: What is a working copy ? All suffixed version are created by a bash script after each non suffixed tag happen.

Comment: The directory of your clone, from where you ran `git describe --tags`

Comment: Then it is `v1.0.0`. I have solved my problem by adding `--exclude=${latestRelease}`.

Comment: Don't you get the longer -nn-g###### suffixes then? Or are some of your tags on the same commit?

Comment: yes I do have a longer suffix, but then I cut on dash and get the left part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your current checkout is a "plain" tag (a tag without a `-cli` suffix), you can get the previous tag via `git describe --tags --exclude '*-*' --abbrev=0 HEAD^`.

- `--exclude '*-*'` removes all tags with a dash within them,
- `--abbrev=0` suppresses the suffix
- `HEAD^` means describe the first parent of the current checked out commit